# NSCollectionView selection and deselection

Tags: macos, cocoa, selection, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I recently got my NSCollectionView worked in the way, that it handles section the right way. I reached this by adding a binding with the Model Key Path "selected". This action hides a blue view, that shows a selection to the user. The Problem is, that i can't deselect my NSCollectionViewItem by clicking outside the image in the view, which is lowest view in the hierarchy of my NSCollectionViewItem. It also didn't deselect the itemView when I'm clicking out of my CollectionView. I tried to get it worked by subclassing my NSCollectionItemView and overriding the selected variable. But, as I said, till now I haven't reached anything to solve my Problem.

Now I'm hoping for help. What can I do?

PS: I did setup the NSControllerView with an arrayController through my MainStoryboard. And Yeah... I just started to programming with swift and cocoa for OS X. But I got some knowledge of cocoa touch. Is there any familiar way to initialise and handle actions of a NSCollectionView like an UICollectionView?

Comment: What do you mean by "it handles section the right way"? Where is the blue view? Which action hides it?

Comment: NSCollectionView had big change in 2015, for instance you could use NSCollectionViewLayout instead of binding. I am not sure which way you want to build your collectionView, but for a selection and highlight capabilities, I have a video covering this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgT04gcDll4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has a WWDC session in 2015 talking about [What's New in NSCollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-225/) with the new API. It talks about `Selection` at 36'33".

The Objective-C Sample Code [CocoaSlideCollection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaSlideCollection/Introduction/Intro.html) shows the selection code in action.

I created a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgT04gcDll4) on Selection as well, Sample code is available [here](https://github.com/harryworld/osx-dev-daily/tree/master/NSCollectionView2015).